# Cookies in Robospice

Tags: cookies, robospice

I want to use cookies in Robospice, I have spice service:

```
    public class JsonSpiceService extends SpringAndroidSpiceService {

    public RestTemplate createRestTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
        FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
        StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
        final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> listHttpMessageConverters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory( httpRequestFactory );
        listHttpMessageConverters.add(jsonConverter);
        listHttpMessageConverters.add(formHttpMessageConverter);
        listHttpMessageConverters.add(stringHttpMessageConverter);
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(listHttpMessageConverters);
        return restTemplate;
    }

    public CacheManager createCacheManager(Application application) throws CacheCreationException {
        CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager();

        List< Class< ? >> classCollection = new ArrayList< Class< ? >>();
        classCollection.add(User.class);
        JacksonObjectPersisterFactory jacksonObjectPersisterFactory = new JacksonObjectPersisterFactory(application);
        cacheManager.addPersister(jacksonObjectPersisterFactory);

        return cacheManager;
    }
}
```

and my Request class:

```
public class Request extends SpringAndroidSpiceRequest<HttpModel> {
private Context context;
private HttpMethod httpMethod;
private MultiValueMap<String, String> body;
private String link;
private String what;
private Object object;

public Request(Context context, HttpMethod httpMethod, MultiValueMap<String, String> body, String link, String what, Object object) {
    super(HttpModel.class);
    this.context = context;
    this.httpMethod = httpMethod;
    this.body = body;
    this.link = link;
    this.what = what;
    this.object = object;
}

@Override
public HttpModel loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
    HttpModel httpModel;
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    HttpEntity<?> requestEntity;
    if (!what.equals(LOGIN)) {
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    } else {
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    }
    requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(body, headers);
    ResponseEntity<HttpModel> responseEntity = getRestTemplate().exchange(link, httpMethod, requestEntity, HttpModel.class);
    httpModel = responseEntity.getBody();

    return httpModel;
}
```

}

How can i get cookie from response?I try add CookieManager to my Request class, but dont'work:

```
    final CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

In postman Cookie look like this:
[enter link description here](http://oi61.tinypic.com/dhb96g.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

[`CookieManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html) is used only for managing cookies in your application's `WebView`s.

You can use `responseEntity.getHeaders().get(COOKIE)`. You can also try `SET_COOKIE` or `SET_COOKIE2` keys instead of `COOKIE`, depending on your server's response.